# Find smallest index that is identical to the value in an array

Tags: javascript, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

**The task** is taken from LeetCode

> Given an array A of distinct integers sorted in ascending order,
>   return the smallest index i that satisfies A[i] == i.  Return -1 if no
>   such i exists.
>
> **Example 1:**
>
> ```
> Input: [-10,-5,0,3,7]
> Output: 3
> Explanation: 
> // For the given array, A[0] = -10, A[1] = -5, A[2] = 0, A[3] = 3, thus the output is 3.
> ```
>
> **Example 2:**
>
> ```
> Input: [0,2,5,8,17]
> Output: 0
> Explanation: 
> // A[0] = 0, thus the output is 0.
> ```
>
> **Example 3:**
>
> ```
> Input: [-10,-5,3,4,7,9]
> Output: -1
> Explanation: 
> // There is no such i that A[i] = i, thus the output is -1.
> ```
>
> **Note:**
>
> 1 <= A.length < 10^4
>
> -10^9 <= A[i] <= 10^9

#### My solution

has time complexity of \$O(n)\$ and space complexity of \$O(1)\$. I start to look from the start to the last element. If I find a value that is greater than `i`, then I can exit early (because there won't be an element that is equal to `i` anymore). If I find `A[i] === i`, then I have a result.

Is there a faster solution than the one provided?

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} A
 * @return {number}
 */
var fixedPoint = function(A) {
    for (let i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
        if (A[i] > i) { return -1; }
        if (A[i] === i) { return i; }
    }
    return -1;
};
```

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with `ary.findIndex((n, i) => n === i)`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I took your previous, invalid solution, and amended it so it does work correctly. So in a way, I am still reviewing your code.

```
function fixedPoint(data)
{
    const lastIndex = data.length - 1;
    if (data[0] > 0 || data[lastIndex] < 0) return -1;
    var left = 0;
    var right = lastIndex - 1;
    while(left <= right) {
        let middle = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
        if (data[middle] == middle) {
            while(middle > 0 && data[middle] == middle) middle--;
            return ++middle;
        }
        if (data[middle] > middle) right = middle;
        else if (data[middle] < middle) left = middle;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I prefer calling a function a function here, but that's a personal choice.

This is basically a *binary search* with a small addition to not trip over arrays like:

`[-10,-5,0,3,4,5,6,7,8,10]`.

This little routine first takes care of 2 edge cases: There is no match when the first value is bigger than zero of when the last value is negative. Then it defines two variables, the `left` and `right` indexes, within which the solution should be found, or not. At first these indexes span the whole array. On every iteration of the `while` loop the searchable section of the array is halved, by either assigning the half-way index `middle` to the `left` or the `right` index based on the value in the array at that half-way location. When a match is found, between the index and the value, it walks backwards if there are more matches before the current one.

Comment: This can be optimized for edge cases. There is no need  to even begin a binary search when the last item in the array is strict negative.

Comment: @dfhwze Yes, or when the first item is bigger than zero. I've now added these two edge cases.

Comment: I'm still contemplating whether performing a binary search to find the value or finding the starting position and eagerly walking up is the most performant.

Comment: @dfhwze It will depend on the values in the array. Both binary searches will perform similarly. The question is which walk will, on average, be the longest. I think walking up from the start, as you defined it, will take longer.

Comment: Seems to me like **worst-case** \$\Theta(N)\$.

Comment: @coderodde Please be more explicit in what you say. What seems to you like what and why?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware You do a \$\Theta(\log N)\$ search first, but then you need to check some of the array entries one by one.

Comment: @coderodde: That happens only in the case that there are multiple matches in sequence and we didn't end up on the first one. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware No, I don't have a better solution.

Answer (score 7):

### Review

Your solution naively walks the array of ascending integers from starting position `s = 0`. In some situations, this means you are walking tons of negative numbers, knowing they can never match an array index, which is always nonnegative.

### Optimization

You could optimize `s` before walking the array. Since array indices are *nonnegative integers*, you should skip walking the array where the values are *strict negative*.

As en example, if `input = [-10000, -9999, ..., 0, 1]` you just want to check 0 and 1.

The way I would optimize the algorithm:

- determine starting point `s`

  - if first item is positive: `s` = 0
  - if last item is strict negative: return -1
  - perform *binary search* to find `s` (you want `s` to hold the first positive integer in the array)
- walk `i` as from `s` to end of array

  - on match: return match
  - on `array[i]` > `i`: return -1
  - on end reached without match: return -1

#### Optimized Time Complexity

~\$0(\lg m)\$ with `m <= n` and `m` being the number of positive integers in the array

Comment: The same is true for very large numbers. Values bigger than the array is long cannot be the same as an array index. The question is, how do you efficiently find these start and end points? Isn't that basically the same problem as you had before? Why not simply do a binary search for the thing you're actually looking for?

Comment: Good observations. The question is when does it pay off performing binary search for both determining the start and end index to walk? Perhaps the size of the array should also be taken into account. Small arrays probably are better of walking from 0 to end.

Comment: @KIKO Software To answer your first question (1) very large values are short-circuited in the check `array[i] > i: return -1`

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware and question (2) given the specific nature of the question, finding the starting position, and walking from here up the array, exiting early on either a match or too big value, is generally faster as finding the value by binary search.

Comment: I don't agree with that, because you're also planning to find the starting position by using a binairy search. Why then not simply use a binary search to search for the match?

Comment: Isn't the worst-case time complexity still O(n), without $lg$? Consider, for example, the array [-1, 0, 1, 2, ..., n-3, n-2].

Comment: @Heinzi Yes, but we are trying to estimate average complexity given all possible distributions.

Comment: @dfhwze: Ah, ok. I'd mention that explicitly, because "O(...) time complexity" without additional modifiers usually means "worst-case time complexity"

Comment: @Heinzi you can edit my answer and modify the complexity if you want. I am talking indeed about an average complexity.

Comment: It's meaningless to talk about average complexity without a distribution on possible inputs, but for any reasonable distribution (any distribution where a negative number is at most as likely as a positive number) this algorithm takes O(n) = O(m) time. It will run on average over half the array.

Comment: @MeesdeVries On average, m = n/2

Comment: @dfhwze, indeed, and O(n) = O(n/2). This is immediate from the definition of the big O, which involves an arbitrary constant.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a simplified version of KIKO Software code, which solves the problem in **O(lg(n))** operations.

```
    function fixedPoint(data)
    {
        const lastIndex = data.length - 1;
        if (lastIndex < 0 || data[0] > 0 || data[lastIndex] < lastIndex) return -1;
        var left = 0;
        var right = lastIndex;
        while(left + 1 < right) {
            let middle = Math.floor((left + right) / 2);
            if (data[middle] >= middle) right = middle;
            else left = middle;
        }
        if(data[left] == left) return left;
        else if (data[right] == right) return right;
        else return -1;
    }
```

Since we are using binary search all the way we get good worst case behaviour.
Also we have ditched the if statement statement for correct answer, and removed another redudant if statement, which reduces the amount of if statements checked from roughly 3.5/iteration to 2 per iteration (remember the while check).
I also fixed the problem where if there was no solution and you were left with left and right being just next to each other and left was not a valid solution, then you would enter an infinite loop, as left would be continously assigned from the middle, but the middle was rounded down to the left. Note that this could only happen in the case where left was never moved (first value would be negative and the second value would be 2 or higher).

If you want to go even faster than this, you can try to find a reasonable way to estimate a good middle suggestion. This kind of approach may yeild lower worst-case performance, but you might be able to reach **O(lg(lg(n)))** average case runtime (I have heard about other algorithms of this type claiming such performance, but I am not familiar with the proofs).
Here is example an following:

```
    function fixedPoint(data)
    {
        const lastIndex = data.length - 1;
        if (lastIndex < 0 || data[0] > 0 || data[lastIndex] < lastIndex) return -1;
        var left = 0;
        var right = lastIndex;
        while(left + 1 < right) {
            let rightWeight = max(left -data[left],1);
            let leftWeight = max(data[right] - right, 1);
            if (rightWeight / 3 > leftWeight ) rightWeight = leftWeight * 3;
            if (leftWeight / 9 > rightWeight ) leftWeight = rightWeight * 9;
            let middle = Math.floor((left * leftWeight + right * rightWeight) / (leftWeight + rightWeight));
            if (data[middle] >= middle) right = middle;
            else left = middle;
        }
        if(data[left] == left) return left;
        else if (data[right] == right) return right;
        else return -1;
    }
```

The idea in the above is to estimate a good middle point based on the predicted crossover point if we draw a line strait between the left and right. I added a max(weight,1), to ensure that the weights are positive and we do not get stuck. To preserve good performance when the right points are valid candidates, we have put a bound on how far to the right we want our middle guess to be, and to preserve worst-case optimal behaviour a less tight boud on how far to the left we allow our guess to be have also been included.
Note that this version may be slower in practice, due to a higher cost of running through each piece of the loop. If you want to use this, then I suggest trying out different values for the bounds on how far to the left or right you allow it to go, and even trying with those bounds turned off entirely.

Comment: Code nicely explained *externally*; put an explanation *in the code*. This is *Code Review*: What [insightful observation about the code in the question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) does your answer provide?

Comment: Asside from fixing some errors in the first version, the insightfull observations are mainly ways to increase the performance (worst-case for the first and and average-case for the second).

Comment: `fixing some errors`, `increase the performance` refers to code from what post?

Comment: Naturally the one KIKO Software wrote, I did mention in the beginning that it was a simplified/modified version of his/her code. Note that the theoretical performance is increased beyond that of the other answers, and the question was specifically for ways to increase performance.

Comment: This is the only correct answer here, in the sense that it is the only one that runs in O(log(n)). One more improvement: you can do an early exit when `data[lastIndex] < lastIndex`, not just when `data[lastIndex] < 0`. Furthermore I prefer taking `right = lastIndex` (without the -1), then you can remove the line `else if (data[right] == right) return right;`.

Comment: And one more note, this code will not work when `data` is empty. Presumably you want a result of -1 in that case, too.

Comment: Good catch, I will add that corner case into the early exit clause.

Comment: Correction to the second part of my first comment: instead of changing `right`, you would have to change `left` to start at -1 instead of 0. Then you would remove the check on `left` at the end, not the check on `right`. But that's probably not worth the legibility.

Comment: While changing to `right = lastIndex` was indeed a correction (it was supposed to be the last valid index), it wouldn't make sense to remove the `else if  (data[right] == right) return right;` line, since it is there to detect if the right point (both the left and the right are supposed to be just after each other at the end) is the correct solution. Setting `left` to start at -1 would be problematic, since it is dereferenced before it is changed, which would cause an index error.